# Not sure why I get errors of missing blocks when trying examples in Gnuradio Companion

Tags: gnuradio, software-defined-radio, usrp

I just started working with GNURadio without much of familiarity about this software. I found a couple examples online and I tried to run them but I get many Missing Block errors.

Thats how it looks like:

[image]

Any idea how to solve this problem please?

Update:

I uninstalled then re-installed GNURadio (3.7.13.4):

[image]

And UHD (UHD_3.14.0.0-release) USRP drives again on my system again (Linux Mint 19 Cinamon).

```
fitpc@fitpc-fitlet2:~$ uhd_usrp_probe
[INFO] [UHD] linux; GNU C++ version 7.3.0; Boost_106501; UHD_3.14.0.0-release
[INFO] [B200] Detected Device: B200mini
[INFO] [B200] Loading FPGA image: /usr/share/uhd/images/usrp_b200mini_fpga.bin...
[INFO] [B200] Operating over USB 3.
[INFO] [B200] Initialize CODEC control...
[INFO] [B200] Initialize Radio control...
[INFO] [B200] Performing register loopback test...
[INFO] [B200] Register loopback test passed
[INFO] [B200] Setting master clock rate selection to 'automatic'.
[INFO] [B200] Asking for clock rate 16.000000 MHz...
[INFO] [B200] Actually got clock rate 16.000000 MHz.
  _____________________________________________________
 /
|       Device: B-Series Device
|     _____________________________________________________
|    /
|   |       Mboard: B200mini
|   |   revision: 3
|   |   product: 30521
|   |   serial: 3164B8E
|   |   name: B200mini
|   |   FW Version: 8.0
|   |   FPGA Version: 7.0
|   |   
|   |   Time sources:  none, internal, external
|   |   Clock sources: internal, external
|   |   Sensors: ref_locked
|   |     _____________________________________________________
|   |    /
|   |   |       RX DSP: 0
|   |   |   
|   |   |   Freq range: -8.000 to 8.000 MHz
|   |     _____________________________________________________
|   |    /
|   |   |       RX Dboard: A
|   |   |     _____________________________________________________
|   |   |    /
|   |   |   |       RX Frontend: A
|   |   |   |   Name: FE-RX1
|   |   |   |   Antennas: TX/RX, RX2
|   |   |   |   Sensors: temp, rssi, lo_locked
|   |   |   |   Freq range: 50.000 to 6000.000 MHz
|   |   |   |   Gain range PGA: 0.0 to 76.0 step 1.0 dB
|   |   |   |   Bandwidth range: 200000.0 to 56000000.0 step 0.0 Hz
|   |   |   |   Connection Type: IQ
|   |   |   |   Uses LO offset: No
|   |   |     _____________________________________________________
|   |   |    /
|   |   |   |       RX Codec: A
|   |   |   |   Name: B200mini RX dual ADC
|   |   |   |   Gain Elements: None
|   |     _____________________________________________________
|   |    /
|   |   |       TX DSP: 0
|   |   |   
|   |   |   Freq range: -8.000 to 8.000 MHz
|   |     _____________________________________________________
|   |    /
|   |   |       TX Dboard: A
|   |   |     _____________________________________________________
|   |   |    /
|   |   |   |       TX Frontend: A
|   |   |   |   Name: FE-TX1
|   |   |   |   Antennas: TX/RX
|   |   |   |   Sensors: temp, lo_locked
|   |   |   |   Freq range: 50.000 to 6000.000 MHz
|   |   |   |   Gain range PGA: 0.0 to 89.8 step 0.2 dB
|   |   |   |   Bandwidth range: 200000.0 to 56000000.0 step 0.0 Hz
|   |   |   |   Connection Type: IQ
|   |   |   |   Uses LO offset: No
|   |   |     _____________________________________________________
|   |   |    /
|   |   |   |       TX Codec: A
|   |   |   |   Name: B200mini TX dual DAC
|   |   |   |   Gain Elements: None
```

[image]

I did the whole "Building and installing GNU Radio from source code" process based on the following page (check at the bottom):

[https://kb.ettus.com/Building_and_Installing_the_USRP_Open-Source_Toolchain_(UHD_and_GNU_Radio)_on_Linux](http://Building%20and%20installing%20GNU%20Radio%20from%20source%20code)

But I still get the same missing box error.

[image: image-1]

Another example gives me some different error with non working FFT graph:

[image]

```
FATAL: RuntimeError: Expected FPGA compatibility number 5, but got 7:
The FPGA build is not compatible with the host code build.
Please run:

 "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/uhd/utils/uhd_images_downloader.py"

Trying to fill up 1 missing channel(s) with null source(s).
This is being done to prevent the application from crashing
due to gnuradio bug #528.
```

And when I try to run /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/uhd/utils/uhd_images_downloader.py I get an error saying No Such Directory.

[image]

Comment: how did you install GNU Radio? Which version do you have? From which version did the flow graph you're trying to open come?

Comment: anyway, this isn't really a signal processing, but a mere GNU Radio usage question, so I'm not very sure it's on-topic here – maybe try the discuss-gnuradio mailing list; they are very helpful

Comment: @Marcus, I installed from the gnuradio.org. It is 3.7.11. The Flow Graph used is a fm_rx.grc and I found it in Github.

Comment: Your flowgraph is trying to instantiate blocks that don't exist in the version you have installed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a problem with usge of a specific software package, and is unrelated to signal processing.

Comment: @MBaz, thanks for the answer, whats the solution in this case? My gnuradio version is the most recent, does it it mean I can't use these flowgraphs sample that I find online? Please, be patient with me, I'm really new to this and try to learn.

Comment: What I would do is examine the flowgraph to find the names (classes) of the missing blocks, then find the current alternatives (asking in gnuradio's mailing list if necessary), and rewrite the flowgraph. Alternatively, I'd try installing  a version of gnuradio that corresponds to the flowgraph.

Comment: @MBaz, Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: also, unless you dug **really** deep on gnuradio.org, you certainly didn't install the ancient 3.7.11 from there.

Comment: @Marcus Müller, I don't know how deeper I should go with it! I mean I uninstalled the 3.7.11 and now I have 3.7.13.4 and still the same thing!

Comment: @Marcus Müller, Please, check my updated posting.

Comment: How can I move this thread or posting to the  GNU Radio forum in stackexchange?

Comment: There's no GNU Radio forum. There's the discuss-gnuradio **mailing list** as I said above.